# How To Create A User in Meetup API

Tags: node.js, angular, meetup

I am currently playing with the meetup API and I want to create users on my application using the meetup API so that these users will be able to join groups, create events and so on.

I am not sure whether what I am asking is possible.

Scenario

```
A user visits www.example.com and signs up for an account, the website hits 
the endpoint to create a user on the meetup API, and the user is redirected 
to their home screen on www.example.com.

The user is then able to upload profile images, search for groups and, and 
and.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you want to programatically sign them up to Meetup? I'd be very surprised if there was an endpoint for that - I expect they'd have to accept Ts&Cs on Meetup itself. I also don't see anything obvious in the API documentation. If you do really need to do this I suggest you ask Meetup directly how you can make it work, but I'd guess the answer is you can't.

Comment: Yeah exactly programatically sign them up to Meetup. okay so it not possible?

Comment: @PhumzileRunRabbitMathonsi did you manage to do this? if Yes, how did you achieve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to do it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest you could get to what you're asking for is to integrate with the [Meetup OAuth](https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/oauth_consumers/) for login & signup to your site.  Once they're logged in via Meetup Oauth, you should be then able to add that user to the group by doing a POST to `/:urlname/members` [as described in the docs](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/:urlname/members/#create).